# What is the most efficient way to filter an array of complex html strings based on words in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter

In a static offline HTML web page, I have a list of complex HTML strings stored in a JavaScript array. Each string can go up to 28k characters, and there can up to 10k strings. It looks like this:

```
[
  "[...]rem;\">Jun 3, 2020 5:34 AM</span></div><div>Here are the requirements for t[...]",
  "[...]rem;\"></div><div>The design <span style=\"color:red\">proposals are actual[...]",
  "[...]un 3, 2020 5:35 AM</span></div><div></div>\n\n<pre>var response = Request.C[...]"
  // ... many more
]
```

These are actually messages stored in HTML. I must find a way to filter them, so for example if I search for the ones that contains the words "*design*" and "*proposals*", I get the second message of the list above as a result. The searched words can be at any position in the HTML string, kind of like `words.every(w => htmlString.indexOf(w) >= 0)`. Notice that I cannot use that code because all the HTML tags will be included in the `indexOf` search and this could produce false positives.

As the JavaScript code is executed in a browser, I have access to the DOM. Filtered messages will be rendered after the filtering is done, using pagination.

My first idea was to loop through all the strings and:

1. Convert them to HTML elements using `document.createElement`,
2. Extract the human-readable text using `innerText`,
3. Search for the words in this flattened-text as it's way easier now without HTML tags using `indexOf`.

I tested it, it works well. But I'm concerned about the performances of this algorithm, especially with a huge amount of messages.

Do you see any other way to filter the message without having to convert all the messages into DOM elements?

Comment: I guess performancewise it will be cheaper to use RegEx on the raw String

Comment: Stick with raw HTML strings. Creating DOM elements will cause a bigger hit. Stings are optimized pretty well in most clients.

Comment: The raw string contains HTML tags that can contain attributes such as style, href, and those can pollute the search. For example, searching for the word *red* would return any HTML string that contains `<span style=\"color:red\">whatever</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Uses Regex that puts desired strings in a capture group.  If capture group ever matches return true.  Excludes `<style>` and `<script>` contents, and `<>` tags by matching them first.

```js
console.log(
[
  "[...]rem;\">Jun 3, 2020 5:34 AM</span></div><div style='color:red'>Here are the requirements for t[...]",
  "[...]rem;\"></div><div>The design <span style=\"color:red\">proposals are actual[...]",
  "[...]un 3, 2020 5:35 AM</span></div><div>red</div>\n\n<pre>var response = Request.C[...]"
  // ... many more
].filter(str=>{
  const re = /<style[^>]+>.*?<\/style>|<script>.*?<\/script>|<[^>]+>|(red|design|proposals)/g
  let m
  while (m = re.exec(str))
    if(m[1]) return true
  return false
})
)
```